# How to Get Transaction Details from return URL from Paypal Payment Gateway using ASP.Net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to integrate sandbox Paypal account in ASP.Net and c#, please help in to the same with full sample code. I wrote the code to get success transaction details as below but get error:

```
if (Request["txn_id"] != "" || Request["txn_id"] != null)
{
    txttranno.Text = Request["txn_id"].ToString();
    string finalPaymentAmount = Request["amt"].ToString();
    string payment_status = Request["st"].ToString();
    txttranno.Text = "$" + finalPaymentAmount;
    //TranStatus.Text = payment_status;
    //string processor = "PayPal";
    txtordno.Text = Session["OrderID"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look: https://github.com/davidduffett/Moolah/tree/master/Moolah/Moolah.

probably this will help you.